# Inventory Updates for disabled items

Tags: inventory

We are looking to place product across various marketplaces, but for internal reasons cannot keep these items active on our main site. Will the inventory for these items update in Magento even if they are disabled? Unfortunately we have not sold any of these types of SKU's in our marketplaces, and are looking at software that will pull our inventory direct from Magento. Version is 1.12.0.0

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by main marketplace ? How are you selling the products from within Magento. If a product is disabled it will not be visible via the website store views. However if you are talking via the API you may still be able to decrement stock from a SKU

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is yes.

Assuming you are using the standard Magento Import/Export (API will work as well), if you are sending product data for products that are disabled in Magento, they will still update.